# static BufferedImage from non-static

Tags: java, static, jar, bufferedimage, non-static

Okay, this is a small part of a big issue I'm trying to have while creating an executable JAR file. I need to move my images so that they can be in another package so that they can be found anywhere. I was loading my BufferedImage using :

```
private static BufferedImage loadRefDigits() {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(new File("src/package/references.png"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(" Error reading reference digits", e);
    }
}
```

However, this image isn't found in the jar, so I'm trying to use:

```
URL imageURL = this.getClass().getResource("/Images/references.png");
```

But this is a non-static method, and I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get the BufferedImage object using this method.

Any help would be very useful thanks!

Comment: Why is that method static and at what point is that code being called?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Just use a static reference to any class in the jar file:

```
URL url = SomeClass.class.getResource("/Images/references.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will set you in the right direction.

```
public static BufferedImage getClasspathImage(String name) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(name);

    URL url = Images.class.getClassLoader().getResource(name);
    if (url == null) {
        String fmt = "cannot find resource [%s]";
        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format(fmt, name));
    }

    try (InputStream stream = url.openStream()) {
        return ImageIO.read(stream);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        String fmt = "cannot read resource [%s] at [%s]";
        String err = String.format(fmt, name, url);
        throw new IllegalStateException(err, e);
    }
}
```